# Have placeholders for logical operators in Roslyn's CSharpScript code string

Tags: c#, roslyn, csharpscript

I am using Roslyn's capabilities to create "Expressions" as strings which are code snippets with placeholders. At run-time the engine substitutes the place holders with their values and evaluates the expression. For instance an expression would look like

```
From =="someEmail@something.com" && SentDate > "12-Nov-2017"
```

Here the words "From" and "SentDate" are placeholders which are substituted with values at runtime. This is how the code looks

```
public class Globals
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string SentDate { get; set; }
    }
void RunCode()
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            code = CSharpScript.Create<bool>(@"From =="someEmail@something.com" && SentDate > "12-Nov-2017"", ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System", "System.IO"), globalsType: typeof(Globals));

            code.Compile();
        }
        object s = code.RunAsync(new Globals() { From = "someEmail@something.com", SentDate = "12-Nov-2017"}).Result.ReturnValue;

        MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
    }
```

Everything works as expected.

Now I want to take this a step further and replace the operators such as && and == by their human readable counterpars such as AND and EqualsTo. So essentially the expression should become

```
From EqualsTo "someEmail@something.com" AND SentDate > "12-Nov-2017"
```

And then somehow in the call to `CSharp.Create` I'd like to substitute AND with && and EqualsTo with ==

Is there a way to achieve that? This is basically to allow users to freely create such expressions using natural language which can then be fed into an evaluation engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Globals object Roslyn is not replacing those names in your code with the corresponding values, your code is actually referencing those fields on that globals object instance.

So this mechanism is not going to work to replace words like AND with &&.

Instead, you could preprocess the script text and replace AND with && before you attempt to execute it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. When you say preprocess are you referring to string replacement or is there a better more elegant way to achieve it?

Comment: I just mean string replacement.  Roslyn cannot help you here because if you give it incorrect C# it won't be able to parse it successfully.